# Some doubts about how to obtain 2 components with the same size into an horizontal linear layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am very new in Android development and I have implement this simple **horizontal LinearLayout** divided in 2 sections having the same space:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:text="View">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:text="Edit">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

It works fine and I obtain this result:

[image]

The 2 sections have the same space. I know that to do it I have to set:

```
android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

on both the components.

It works fine but why? What exactly means set the width to 0px and the weight to 1? Is it a sort of convetions of what?

Answer (score 1):

> It works fine but why? What exactly means set the width to 0px and the weight to 1?

First, `LinearLayout` adds up all of the requested specific sizes along the axis of the `LinearLayout`. In your case, it is a `horizontal` `LinearLayout`, so it adds up the `layout_width` values. In your case, 0px + 0px = 0px.

`LinearLayout` then determines how many pixels are left over. Let's pretend that your device has a 1080p screen. In that case, 1080px - 0px = 1080px.

Then, it adds up the requested `layout_weight` values. If you put a `weightSum` on the `LinearLayout`, this part is skipped, as the `weightSum` is used directly. In your case, 1 + 1 = 2.

Then, it allocated the leftover pixels (1080px) based on the fraction of the sum of the weights for the widget. So, the first button gets 1080px * 1 / 2 = 540px. The second button gets 1080px * 1 / 2 = 540px.

As a result, the two buttons are sized the same, with 540px width.

Comment: If I set `layout_weight` to 2 for button 1 and 1 for button 2, then will the button 2 get 2/3 and button 1 get 1/3 of the remaining space?

Comment: @harry: Not in this case, where we have leftover pixels. Higher weights means you get a bigger portion of the leftover pixels. Outside of the equal-weights scenario, I tend to use percentages (e.g., weights of 50, 30, and 20 to give the three widgets 50%, 30%, and 20% of the remaining pixels) to help keep it simple. Of course, nowadays, you can achieve similar results with `PercentRelativeLayout`.

Comment: So in case of leftover pixels, button 1 will get all the remaining space?

Comment: @harry: I am confused by your naming scheme. Let's say that we have Button A and Button B. You give Button A a weight of 2. You give Button B a weight of 1. 1 + 2 = 3. So, Button A gets 2/3rds of the available pixels. Button B gets 1/3rd of the available pixels.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was asking about. Sorry about the naming scheme.

Answer (score 0):

By setting both to `android:layout_weight="1"` you tell, that this components have equal width on their parent. You can write also `android:layout_weight="2"` or even `android:layout_weight="100"` - it doesn't matter. If you write on one button `android:layout_weight="2"`, and on the second `android:layout_weight="1"` - the first button will take two times more space than the other. By setting weight, you are setting ratio between components in layout